# Integration with base 10

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have to calculate the following integral:
$$
\int_{1}^{2}10^{x/2}dx
$$

I simplified it as follows:
$$
\int_{1}^{2}10^{x/2}dx=\int_{1}^{2}e^{\ln10^{x/2}}dx=\int_{1}^{2}e^{\ln10\times\frac{x}{2}}dx=\frac{1}{0.5\ln(10)}[e^{\ln10\frac{x}{2}}]_{1}^{2}
$$
 and then 
$$
\frac{1}{0.5\ln(10)}[e^{\ln10\frac{x}{2}}]_{1}^{2}=\frac{1}{0.5\ln(10)}[e^{\ln10}-e^{\ln5}]=\frac{5}{0.5\ln(10)}
$$

When I use Wolfram to double check, I get a different answer. I would be grateful if someone could point out the mistake in my solution. Thanks!

Comment: It gave me an answer of 5.9392 which is different than mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your lower limit is wrong: $e^{(\ln 10)\times\frac{1}{2}}=e^{\ln\sqrt{10}}$ and not $e^{\ln 5}$.

Answer (score 1):

This step is wrong since L.H.S.$\not =$ R.H.S.:

> $$\frac{1}{0.5ln(10)}[e^{ln10\frac{x}{2}}]_{1}^{2}=\frac{1}{0.5ln(10)}[e^{ln10}-e^{ln5}]$$

It should be as follows:
$$\int_{1}^{2}10^{x/2}dx=2\int_{1}^{2}10^{x/2}d(\frac{x}{2})$$
$$=\frac{2\cdot 10^{x/2}}{ \ln 10}\big|^2_1$$
$$=\frac{2(10-\sqrt{10})}{\ln 10}$$
$$=5.9392$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\int 10^{\frac{x}{2}}\space\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=\frac{x}{2}$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{1}{2}\space\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$2\int 10^{u}\space\space\text{d}u=$$
$$2\cdot\frac{10^u}{\ln(10)}+\text{C}=$$
$$2\cdot\frac{10^{\frac{x}{2}}}{\ln(10)}+\text{C}$$